# Construction of a classifying map from a connection 1-form

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, connections, classifying-spaces

From a connection 1-form on $M$, I can construct a parallel transport from which in turn I can construct a classifying map $M \to BG$.
Is there a construction of such a classifying map *directly* from a connection 1-form?

Comment: @JimStasheff, I'm slightly confused: To talk about a connection 1-form on $M$ you will have some principal G-bundle $P\to M$ to work over, and to such a bundle there is a unique classifying map $\phi:M\to BG$ such that $P=\phi^*EG$.

Comment: @ChrisGerig: of course the classifying map is only unique up to homotopy.  If one has a particular model for BG in mind (e.g. a Grassmannian) then it may be helpful to have a construction that is more canonical.  For instance one might ask if there is a continuous a map from the affine space of 1-forms to the mapping space Map(M, BG).  Of course one could just take a constant map landing at a classifying map for the bundle in question, so I guess I'm not sure what additional properties to ask for.

Comment: Chris, I was trying to talk as a physicist ;-): A connection 1-form A gives a covariant derivative d+[A, ]. Then I was thinking of the model of BG as the realization of the nerve of G.  For now I would settle for the following: (how) does a connection 1-form determine transition functions for the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

17.11 of

- [Peter W. Michor: Topics in Differential Geometry. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, Vol. 93 American Mathematical Society, Providence, 2008](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf)

constructs transition functions for the bundle (in step 5 of the proof),
for any complete Ehresmann connection whose holonomy Lie algebra is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks Peter Exactly what I want, at least under the conditions you state. No access to a library until next week. Any chance it's also in one of your papers available on line?

Comment: Just click on it. I gave a link to the pdf file.